# Error in gridviewUpdating asp.net with a timestamp update

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I have two buttons, SetIn and SetOut. They both have the commandName UPDATE ( I have two buttons as I'd like the text to be different on the button depending on the value of one field in the row.

I'm getting a problem in that when I run the update SQL statement, it throws an error at me. It says:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '14'.

This means that there is an issue with the date and time stamp that I am trying to update the row with (I'm making the update at 14.02pm).

My aspx.cs page code is:

```
  protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
     Label id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_Index") as Label;
     int rowToUpdate = Int32.Parse(id.Text);
     con = new SqlConnection(cs);

     int scopeValue;
     con = new SqlConnection(cs);
     cmd = new SqlCommand();

     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT in_scope FROM " + databaseName + " WHERE id = '" + rowToUpdate + "'";
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowToUpdate);
     cmd.Connection = con;

     try
     {
         con.Open();
         scopeValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
         //database_entries.Text = recordCount.ToString();
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
     }

    string modifiedBy = userManagement.getWeldID();
    string updateDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    {
        if (scopeValue == 1)
        {
           // Label id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_Index") as Label;
            string sqlStatement = "";
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
           // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlStatement = @"update dbo.Fair_Use_InScope_MIF_Alex_temp set in_scope = '0', modified_by = " + modifiedBy + ", date_updated = " + updateDate + " where id = '" + rowToUpdate + "'";

            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ShowData();
        }
        if (scopeValue == 0)
        {
           // Label id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_Index") as Label;
            string sqlStatement = "";
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);
           // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlStatement = @"update dbo.Fair_Use_InScope_MIF_Alex_temp set in_scope = '1', modified_by = " + modifiedBy + ", date_updated = " + updateDate + " where id = '" + rowToUpdate + "'";
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ShowData();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm basically trying to get the scopeValue (0 or 1) of the row, and if the Update command is called, and the scopeValue was previously 0, set it to 1 now and vice versa. I also need to update the time that the change was made and who made the change in that row. (these are both displayed in the gridview)

Any help would be much appreciated as I am a beginner to ASP.NET and C# and SQL SERVER!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a DateTime as a string (without even enclosing single quotes `date_updated = '" + updateDate + "'`) and that will always cause problems.

It's better to use parameters in your query. This prevents SQL injection, improves readability, ensures type safety, no more worries about the correct use of quotation marks etc.

```
        string sqlStatement = "UPDATE dbo.Fair_Use_InScope_MIF_Alex_temp SET in_scope = 0, modified_by = @modifiedBy, date_updated = @updateDate WHERE (id = @rowToUpdate)";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@modifiedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = modifiedBy;
            command.Parameters.Add("@updateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            command.Parameters.Add("@rowToUpdate", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 35;

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm no longer getting that error message! Can I ask why the value of the rowtoupdate is 35? Thanks!

Comment: It's a made-up number to show 3 different data types in my example. You can change that into `rowToUpdate`